# understand a macro to convert user requested size to a malloc usable size

Tags: c, alignment, malloc, glibc, memory-alignment

```
INTERNAL_SIZE_T            size_t
#define SIZE_SZ            (sizeof(INTERNAL_SIZE_T))

MALLOC_ALIGNMENT           MAX (2 * sizeof(INTERNAL_SIZE_T),
                  __alignof__ (long double))

#define MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK      (MALLOC_ALIGNMENT - 1)

struct malloc_chunk {

  /* prev_size and size makes the header */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      prev_size;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      size;       /* Size in bytes, including overhead. */

  struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk;

  struct malloc_chunk* fd_nextsize; /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk_nextsize;
};


/* The smallest possible chunk */
#define MIN_CHUNK_SIZE        (offsetof(struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))

/* The smallest possible aligned chunk */
#define MINSIZE  \
  (unsigned long)(((MIN_CHUNK_SIZE+MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK) & ~MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK))

/* Convert user request to a usable size */
#define request2size(req)                                         \
  (((req) + SIZE_SZ + MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK < MINSIZE)  ?             \
   MINSIZE :                                                      \
   ((req) + SIZE_SZ + MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK) & ~MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK)
```

A malloc chunk (`struct malloc_chunk`) is actually 2 parts : the header which contains `prev_size` (The size of the previous chunk) and `size` (Size of current chunk) and the body which is the part of the chunk returned to the user.Once the chunk is freed, the space that was used by the user is now reused to store 
the `fd` and `bk` pointers (freelist pointers).

when a user asks for memory (`malloc(size_t)`), the user requested size is first converted to a malloc usable size. The rule is that the malloc chunk
should have at least enough space to store the header information and the freelist pointers (When the chunk is later freed), thus, we have a minimal
size chunk of size `MIN_CHUNK_SIZE` but malloc guarantees that chunks are aligned and therefore the minimal aligned chunk have size of `MINSIZE`.

The problem is in the `request2size` macro. Normally, to do the conversion, according to the description above, we calculate the value of 
`size = (user requested size + the header size (2 * SIZE_SZ))` and then proceed with the verifications:

```
if (size < MINSIZE) 
    final_size = MINSIZE;   /* The size is not big enough to make a usable chunk so just round it to MINSIZE */
else 
    final_size = (size + MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK) & ~MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK; /* The chunk is big enough to contain the header and free list pointers, we just need to make sure it is aligned */
```

But that's not happening in the `request2size` macro. It adds only one `SIZE_SZ` unit to `req` (The header needs 2) and `MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK` is added before comparing.
I tried to understand the logic behind the macro but i couldn't get it. Is there someone who can explain how does this macro work (How does it pad and align the chunk) ?

For more information, you can check out malloc.c source code of ptmalloc2 on this [github](https://github.com/sploitfun/lsploits/blob/master/glibc/malloc/malloc.c) repo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers